# Removing Redundant Entries In Access Log

Tags: php, bash, cookies, grep, cron

I coded some php script for a webpage at our company, and it records the ip address, the date and time stamp of each visitor, and it injects a cookie into the clients browser to keep track of the number of lifetime visits. It prints all of this information into an Access Log in this format.

```
Visitor IP: 173.11.250.189
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 09:47:16am
# of Visits:1

Visitor IP: 173.11.250.189
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 09:47:40am
# of Visits:2

Visitor IP: 173.11.250.189
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 09:47:46am
# of Visits:3

Visitor IP: 173.11.250.192
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 09:57:40am
# of Visits:1

Visitor IP: 173.11.250.192
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 09:57:54am
# of Visits:2

Visitor IP: 173.11.250.189
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 10:20:04am
# of Visits:4

Visitor IP: 173.11.250.176
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 10:20:32am
# of Visits:1
```

If if cookie present = false then it just injects a new cookie with a value of 1, and it prints a default value of 1 in the Access Log.

Once a week I have a cron job that runs a script that emails this log to myself as well as the company owners, then it creates an archive of this log, and lastly it clears the log and starts fresh.

This works great except for one fact....redundant entries.
I'm trying to find a way to remove redundancies in this log before it gets emailed to the owners and myself. So for instance, the two entries listed above both share the same IP address but they mark two separate visits. With the redundant entries I would like to only keep the entry with the highest # of visits while removing the redundant entries that contain a lower # of visits.

The filtered output of the sample given above would be something similar to:

```
Visitor IP: 173.11.250.189
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 10:20:04am
# of Visits:4

Visitor IP: 173.11.250.192
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 09:57:54am
# of Visits:2

Visitor IP: 173.11.250.176
Date = Wednesday 12-23-2015
Time = 10:20:32am
# of Visits:1
```

Where only the details for the most recent visits are stored, and where it found multiple visits from the same IP it kept only the most recent record which had the higher value for # of visits.

Any ideas?

I haven't really been able to come up with any solutions due to the fact that it requires the filtering to take into account 4 lines at a time and not just a line to line filtering since each 4 lines is an "entry". I'm quite stumped on this one.

Best Regards,
Matthew O.

Comment: Try to provide a more representative sample input with all possible scenarios, together with its desired output and what you tried so far. Also, you are tagging with both bash and php, would you consider solutions in both technologies?

Comment: Yes, a solution in either php or bash script would be fine, I have no preference. We could even go so far as to just have it update the log on a returning visit as opposed to creating a new entry. I'll post a larger section.

Comment: OK. Try to read [ask] so that you see the workflow here: provide your sample input / desired output together with what you tried. Then we can help you!

Comment: Ok. I think I fixed the question. Sorry about that. I provided a larger sample input and a sample output.

Comment: So what is unique in every paragraph? The IP alone or also all the other lines?

Comment: The IP is unique and the # of visits is unique. However the issue I'm trying to solve is redundant entries that have the same IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Records are separated by blank lines.
# Each line is one field.

sed -n '{1!G;h;$p}' $1 | awk 'BEGIN {RS="";FS="\n";OFS="\n";ORS="\n\n"}
{
  if(!seen[$4]++)
    {
    print $4,$3,$2,$1
    }
}'
```

Save the script as `RedundantRecordRemover` , make it an executable,
and run it like :

```
./RedundantRecordRemover your_log_file
```

In fact you could replace the original file by :

```
./RedundantRecordRemover your_log_file >> tempfile ; mv tempfile your_log_file
```

**The Idea:**

The `sed` script reverses the text from the file you have fed to it before passing it to the `awk` script. This text reversal is useful in targeting the last entry for each IP address.

**Requirement:**

Each record in the input log file must be separated by a blank line. This is what your sample input file says.

**Downfall:**

There could be `speed bottleneck` for large log files. Unfortunately I couldn't test for large log files in my environment. I guess this should be good for files of few Megabyte sizes.

**Notes:** I assumed that -

1. the last appearance of an IP in the log is indeed its last occurrence. Well! this is a log file after all.
2. the order in which the IPs are listed in the output file is not at all important, if not some more tweaks need to be done.

**Edit:**

Incorporating @fedorqui's suggestion, another way of writing the script would be :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Records are separated by blank lines.
# Each line is one field.

awk 'BEGIN {RS="";FS="\n";OFS="\n";ORS="\n\n"}
{
  if(!seen[$4]++)
    {
    print $4,$3,$2,$1
    }
}' <(tac $1)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.
=)

Comment: You're welcome pal. Just curious to know - how big are your log files?

Comment: Not that big. I setup a cron job that handles it every week so it generally stays a manageable size. You were correct in assuming that the last entry for an ip is the most recent, and you were also correct in assuming that the order for the output is not important so long as the 4 line groups stay together and don't get jumbled up.

Comment: Fair enough... The lines shoudnt get jumbled with this one because reversing the text still ensures that the 4 lines in a record stays together..

Comment: Nice! Note you can also reverse a file with `tac file`, so you can even say `awk '...' <(tac file)`

Comment: @fedorqui : `tac` was a nice touch ! Thankyou. I never knew such a command existed. Do `tac`  have any performance advantage over `sed` in this case?

Comment: Not sure, but I prefer it over `sed` because it is more readable :-D